# Block call by criteria (CallKit)

Tags: ios, callkit

I'm trying to block calls using CallKit's Call Directory Extension where calling number satisfies some criteria  (Area Code, Country Code, etc)

Apple's documentation state:

> This is useful for apps that, for example, maintain a database of known solicitors, or allow the user to block any numbers that match a set of criteria.

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit)

The line: "**or allow the user to block any numbers that match a set of criteria**" seems to be what I am interested in but I can't seem to figure it out.

Looking at [Block calls with CallKit using regex or wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650557/block-calls-with-callkit-using-regex-or-wildcard) it appears that in 18' this was not possible, has this changed? Is Apple's documentation off or am I interpreting it incorrectly?

Comment: As far as I can see, that comment was never correct. The API has only ever (and still) supported blocking specific phone numbers.

Comment: @rmaddy Alright, thanks. Bummer.

Comment: It may be that the comment means the app can support the entry of some sort of "criteria" by the user but the app must then calculate all matching individual numbers and block and and every one. And apparently there is an undocumented limit on how many numbers an app can block. So blocking every possible phone number in the 333 area code (made up example) might not even be possible because (in the US or Canada) that would be 10,000,000 phone numbers.

Comment: @rmaddy haha I was thinking about doing that. Well, I'll wait for Apple to open up more hopefully. Thank you

Comment: Is there any update? I am interested in this as well. I thought they would already support this.